# SqlCommand object - set it and forget it?

Tags: c#, sqlcommand

I'm using SqlClient.SqlCommand object to run a few stored procs on my db.  Normally when I run these manually via Query Analyzer they take up to 15 minutes to complete.

So obviously when I run them using the SqlCommand object I get a SqlCommand timeout.

I know I could set the timeout property to a very high number, but I'm wondering if alternatively there's a way to just kickoff the procs and disconnect. I don't need a return value.

Any suggestions?  I'm not interested in optimizing the processing time of each sp here, just trying to determine if there's a 'set it and forget it' option.

Here's the content of the SqlCommand object:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"update tbl_SYS_DATE set RPT_DATE = @inputDate
                                                    exec sp_Get_Bp_Data1
                                                    exec sp_Get_Bp_Data2          
                                                    exec sp_Get_Bp_Data3
                                                    exec sp_channel_data1
                                                    exec sp_channel_data2
                                                    exec sp_channel_data3
                                                    ", con))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an async method, like BeginExecuteNonQuery.  The timeout is ignored for that.

Comment: +1 - beat me by 22 seconds (but no link, so who really won?:-) )

Comment: If you use this method, make sure you don't put your SqlConnection in a using clause or the connection will be disposed before the command is done executing.

Answer (score 4):

Use the asynchronous method call BeginExecuteNonQuery. From [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx)

> The CommandTimeout property will be ignored during asynchronous method calls such as BeginExecuteReader.

Answer (score 0):

You could run that code from a background thread.  You could look into the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) object.